# Repeated calls to SharedPreferences apply() causes OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using a Firebase `onChildAdded` listener to store certain pieces of data persistently in my Android app. When the app starts, this might fire thousands of times. Each time this fires, I am using SharedPreferences `apply` to write a simple key / value pair. The keys and values themselves aren't very large, but there might be a few thousand stored in SharedPreferences.

I was excited about using `apply` because it does some magic around caching in-memory and delaying the actual SharedPreferences XML write. However, I am finding that if I call `apply` 1,000-2,000 times within a few seconds, I get an OutOfMemory error.

Internally, SharedPreferencesImpl seems to be creating a new `Map` based off the old `Map` if writes to the actual XML are still queued. However, this is causing what seems to be a few thousand `Map` entries on the Java heap (I believe), and I'm getting an `OutOfMemory` error.

Maybe I should call `commit` every 50 or so times I call `apply` - this way I won't run into OutOfMemory errors, although I may see a small performance hit? What should I do? That seems kind of hacky anyway.

Comment: shared preferences are not meant to store such large data's. You should opt for sql database instead

Comment: I find it hard to believe SharedPreferences can't store a few thousand key / value pairs, where each key and value is just a few characters (50 at most).

Comment: Yes but that's the problem with your code

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to use a Firebase single event listener on the location, `put` my thousands of items, THEN call `apply()`. You also have to keep track of the keys you've seen already (a `HashSet` of `String`s).

Then, make a `ChildEventListener`, and just ignore the `onChildAdded` if the key exists in my `HashSet`.